# Create Nothing from falsey values using Returns library

Tags: python, option-type

Using the [Returns](https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/maybe.html#maybe) library, I have a function that filters a list. I want it to return `Nothing` if the list is empty (i.e. falsey) or `Some([...])` if the list has values.

`Maybe` seems to be mostly focused on "true" nothing, being `None`. But I'm wondering if there's a way to get `Nothing` from a falsey value without doing something like

```
data = []

result = Some(data) if len(data) > 0 else Nothing
```

Comment: The boolean evaluation of an empty list is False.  
result = Some(data) if data else Nothing

However, why not:

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently submitted my comment before it was finished.
I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  What do you want result to return.  Do you want to return None if data is empty?  if so, use  "result = data or None".  

The boolean evaluation of an empty list is False.  
result = Some(data) if data else Nothing

Comment: Trying to do something like `Maybe.from_optional(data)` to get `Nothing` for an empty list or `Some([ ... ])` if the list is not empty. Because that would apply to other falsely values too, so if there was some method or function to parse falsely values in `Maybe` then I wouldn't need to create a bunch of custom checks for each type of falsey value.
I understand why it's not a default, because an empty list is different than `None`, so I was wondering if there's some other built in way to parse falsey values in `Maybe`

Comment: I added an answer below based on your comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have at least a few options.  (1) You can create a new class that inherits from Maybe, and then override any methods you like, (2) create a simple function that returns Nothing is data is false, else returns Maybe.from_optional(data) {or whatever other method of Maybe you prefer), or (3) create your own container as per the returns documentation at https://returns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/create-your-own-container.html.

Here is a class called Possibly, that inherits from Maybe and overrides the from_optional class method.  You can add similar overrides for other methods following this pattern.

```
from typing import Optional
from returns.maybe import Maybe, _NewValueType, _Nothing, Some

class Possibly(Maybe):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @classmethod
    def from_optional(
        cls, inner_value: Optional[_NewValueType],
    ) -> 'Maybe[_NewValueType]':
        """
        Creates new instance of ``Maybe`` container based on an optional value.

        """
        if not inner_value or inner_value is None:
            return _Nothing(inner_value)
        return Some(inner_value)



data = [1,2,3]
empty_data = []


print(Possibly.from_optional(data))
print(Possibly.from_optional(empty_data))
```

Here are two equivalent functions:

```
from returns.maybe import Maybe, _Nothing

data = [1,2,3]
empty_data = []

def my_from_optional(anything):
    if not anything:
        return _Nothing(anything)
    else:
        return Maybe.from_optional(anything)

def my_from_optional(anything):
    return Maybe.from_optional(anything) if anything else _Nothing(anything)

print(my_from_optional(data))
print(my_from_optional(empty_data))
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately still not enough rep to upvote. But I will eventually!